# FprintF from linklist to file

Tags: c, linked-list, file-handling, printf

I have added the Fprintf into the SavePacket function but it doesn't recognise pos->destination like it does withing the outpackets function, How do i addapt the code so it takes the data saved in my Link-List and FprintF's it to my File?

```
void outputPackets(node **head)
{


/*********************************************************
* Copy Node pointer so as not to overwrite the pHead     *
* pointer                                                *
**********************************************************/
node *pos = *head;

/*********************************************************
* Walk the list by following the next pointer            *
**********************************************************/
while(pos != NULL) {
    printf("Source: %i Destination: %i Type: %i Port: %i \n", pos->Source, pos->Destination, pos->Type, pos->Port, pos->next);
    pos = pos->next ;
}
printf("End of List\n\n");
}



void push(node **head, node **aPacket)
{
/*********************************************************
* Add the cat to the head of the list (*aCat) allows the *
* dereferencing of the pointer to a pointer              *
**********************************************************/
(*aPacket)->next = *head;
*head = *aPacket;
}

node *pop(node **head)
{
/*********************************************************
* Walk the link list to the last item keeping track of   *
* the previous. when you get to the end move the end     *
* and spit out the last Cat in the list                  *
**********************************************************/
node *curr = *head;
node *pos = NULL;
if (curr == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
} else {
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        pos = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (pos != NULL) // If there are more cats move the reference
    {
        pos->next = NULL;
    } else {         // No Cats left then set the header to NULL (Empty list)
        *head = NULL;
    }
}
return curr;
```

/*********************************************************************
Save Pakcet Code function
/*********************************************************************

```
void SavePacket(){

FILE *inFile ;
char inFileName[10] = { '\0' } ;

printf("Input file name : ") ;
scanf("%s", inFileName) ;

unsigned long fileLen;

//Open file
inFile = fopen(inFileName, "w+");
if (!inFile)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", &inFile);
exit(0);

 }

 fprintf("Source: %i Destination: %i Type: %i Port: %i \n", pos->Source, pos->Destination, pos->Type, pos->Port, pos->next);



}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should look at [the function signatures](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) of `printf` and `fprintf`. Your `printf` in `outputPackets` was good. However, here is `fprintf` signature:

```
int fprintf(FILE* stream, const char* format, ...);
```

The first argument should be a `FILE*`. However, you called your function like that:

```
fprintf("Source: %i Destination: %i Type: %i Port: %i \n", pos->Source, pos->Destination, pos->Type, pos->Port, pos->next);
```

In your call, the first argument is the format string while it should be a `FILE*`. That's why you don't get the result you expected.

Moreover, in both your calls to `printf` and `fprintf`, the last value you give, `pos->next`, is useless and you can remove it.

**EDIT:** To be exact, that line should have been

```
fprintf(inFile, "Source: %i Destination: %i Type: %i Port: %i \n", pos->Source, pos->Destination, pos->Type, pos->Port);
```

Comment: Ok i changed the Code to this, 
int fprintf((inFile, const char* pos->Source, pos->Destination, pos->Type, pos->Port);
but im still getting an error saying 'Expected declaration specifiers or '......' before ) token'

Comment: @user1949280 Be careful, you put two `(` at the beginning. And you left a stray `const char*` in the middle. Whatever, I completed my answer.

Comment: int fprintf(inFile, const char*; pos->Source, pos->Destination, pos->Type, pos->Port);

has one error sayin expected ) before const, but this will add more problems?

Comment: @user1949280 Meh, `const char*` is the type. Pass the full string, not the type :p

Comment: Now im getting my original error again saying the pos->Source etc is undefined